# List of file's extension can be edited text in an editor

Tags: c#, asp.net

Try to explain so clearly, hope you can understand my problem.

My aspx page allows client uploading file (allows all extension of file) into a root folder. Then in that aspx page, it has an Repeater control to display all files uploaded.

[image]

I'm stuck in finding the way to detect which file can be edited in an editor control.

For example: `if item= xml file --> show Edit Text`

```
if item= source code file ---> show Edit Text
```

In `Repeater1_ItemDataBound` function, in the last `else if` statement, it is added the `Edit Text` function whenever the item is: textfile, source code, xml file... more more...

In my code below, I can do it which some file's extension, but I know it not enough.

Help!!!

If you dont really understand, please ask!!!

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand"
OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
 <tr>
  <td>
     <asp:Label ID="imagelabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> 
   </td>
   <td>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFolder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
   </td>
   <td >
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="<img src='pic/trash.png'/> Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Path") +"," +  Eval("Type")%>'CommandName="Delete"> </asp:LinkButton>
   </td>
    <td>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="<img src='pic/gear--pencil.png'/> Rename" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Path") + "," +  Eval("Type") + "," + Eval("Name")%>'CommandName="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
    </td>
    <td>
        asp:LinkButton  ID="lbtnEditText" runat="server" Text="" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Path") + "," + Eval("Name")%>'CommandName="EditText" OnCommand="Button1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
     </td>

 </tr>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Take a look at my `Repeater1_ItemDataBound` function:

```
    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
      if (((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["Type"].ToString() == "D")// if item= folder
         {
           ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("imagelabel")).Text = "<img src='pic/folder.png'>";
         }
      else
        {
          string fileExtension = ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["Extension"].ToString();
            if (fileExtension.Equals(".gif") || fileExtension.Equals(".jpg") || fileExtension.Equals(".png"))
               ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("imagelabel")).Text = "<img src='pic/gallery.jpg'>";
            else if (fileExtension.Equals(".doc") || fileExtension.Equals(".docx"))
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("imagelabel")).Text = "<img src='pic/doc.gif'>";
            else if (fileExtension.Equals(".pdf"))
                ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("imagelabel")).Text = "<img src='pic/pdf.gif'>";
            else if (fileExtension.Equals(".xls"))
                 ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("imagelabel")).Text = "<img src='pic/excel.gif'>";
            else if???
                {
                  ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("imagelabel")).Text = "<img src='pic/Text.gif'>";
//add Edit Text function here
                  ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbtnEditText")).Text = "<img src='pic/pe.png'/> Edit Text";
                }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a list of all extesions you consider a textfile and add them to your code.
Something like:

```
var textExtensions = new HashSet<string> { ".txt", ".css", ".htm", ".html", ".xml", ".c",  /*etc.*/ };

...

else if textExtensions.Contains(fileExtension)
{
  ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("imagelabel")).Text = "<img src='pic/Text.gif'>";
  //add Edit Text function here
  ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbtnEditText")).Text = "<img src='pic/pe.png'/>Edit Text";
}
```

If you want a list of extensions that are generally considered a textfile have a look at the table in [MIME Types in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742440.aspx).

Pick all extensions of which the Type/subtype column starts with "text"

Comment: thank, I vote your answer as the best answer because I need the list of file extension. Thank!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a list with "editable" file extensions and check if extension is in there.
Something like that I think,

```
var editable = new[]{ ".xml", ".txt".... et cetera };
else if(editable.Contains(fileExtension))
{
    display edit button
}
```

And you can do even better.
You can create class representing file info.

```
class FileInfo
{
    public string Extension { get; set; }
    public string IconPath { get; set; }
    public string Editable { get; set; }
}

//somewhere inside you class
var files = new List<FileInfo>();
files.Add(new FileInfo(){ Extension = ".txt", IconPath = "<img src='pic/pe.png'/>", Editable = true});
// do this for all extensions

var fileInfo = file.First(f => f.Extension.Equals(fileExtension))
((Label)e.Item.FindControl("imagelabel")).Text = fileInfo.IconPath;
if(fileInfo.Editable)
{
    ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbtnEditText")).Text = "<img src='pic/pe.png'/> Edit Text";
}
```